# Some question about python's inheritance, import

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python, but skilled on java. Now I'm facing a annoying question when training on python3.5, I have such a src structure:

```
/project-root  
--main.py  
--ModelImpl.py #subclass of BaseModel  
--ActionImpl.py #subclass of BaseAction  
--/base  
----BaseModel.py #base class of all  
----BaseAction.py #subclass of BaseModel  
----modulescript.py
```

in main.py:

```
from ModelImpl import ModelImpl
from ActionImpl import ActionImpl
modelImpl = ModelImpl()
actionImpl = ActionImpl()
```

in modulescript.py:

```
from BaseAction import BaseAction
baseAction = BaseAction()
```

in BaseModel.py:

```
class BaseModel: 
  def __init__(self):
    print("BaseModel")
```

in BaseAction.py:

```
from .BaseModel import BaseModel
class BaseAction(BaseModel):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print("BaseAction")
```

in ModelImpl.py:

```
from base.BaseModel import BaseModel
class ModelImpl(BaseModel):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print("ModelImpl")
```

in ActionImpl.py:

```
from base.BaseAction import BaseAction
class ActionImpl(BaseAction):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print("ActionImpl")
```

Now when I input python3 main.py in terminal, I got printed result:

```
BaseModel   
ModelImpl   
BaseModel   
BaseAction   
ActionImpl
```

but if I input python3 module function.py, I got error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "modulescript.py", line 1, in (module) from BaseAction import BaseAction
>
> File "/home/jerry/projects/test/python/base/BaseAction.py", line 1, in (module) from .BaseModel import BaseModel SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

I found that It's cause by import statement in BaseAction.py:

```
from .BaseModel import BaseModel
```

If I change to `from BaseModel import BaseModel`, the modulescript.py runs ok, but the main.py will got a error:

> File "main.py", line 225, in (module) from ActionImpl import ActionImpl
>
> File "/home/jerry/projects/test/python/ActionImpl.py", line 1, in (module) from base.BaseAction import BaseAction
>
> File "/home/jerry/projects/test/python/base/BaseAction.py", line 1, in (module) from BaseModel import BaseModel
>
> ImportError: No module named 'BaseModel'

Oops. annoying!
In java, you can import any Class from any where if you provide the right path of the class like `import com.domain.MyClass;`

so, what's the right way to import in python?

Comment: You should note, your module-structure isn't very pythonic. Normally, you don't just make a single module per-class, but group related classes into modules. But that isn't really relevant to the question...

Comment: try changing it to `from base.BaseModel import BaseModel`

Answer (score 0):

This is Python, not Java, you group modules related to eachother in a single package, which is a folder.

To be able to import from a package, you must do a few things first.

1. Create `__init__.py` in your package to let interpreter know that it's a package. If there's no such file in a folder, it won't even budge whether you want to import from there or not, it's not a package to it and that's all.
2. Additionally, if you want (and you should when you're creating a package for others to use) import classes functions and etc in your `__init__.py` to allow to import them from the package itself directly.

I made a simple example:

`project tree`:

```
/root
  test.py
  /examplepkg
    __init__.py
    somemodule.py
```

EDIT: if you want examplepkg to have a "nested" package, as in, package it depends on in some way, you create another folder, and put another `__init__.py` in it and do the same thing, then in `__init__.py` of examplepkg you can further "export" it for the top level modules to see. How you do it is up to you, just be consistent.

`somemodule.py`:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("New Instance of SomeClass!")
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from .somemodule import SomeClass # you could see it as exporting
```

`test.py`:

```
from examplepkg import SomeClass


SomeClass()
```

For more information, [read this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Thx for your patient answer. Today I tried create a new python project using eclipse, and the import statement in BaseAction.py is "from base.BaseModel import BaseModel". When using eclipse built-in run as Python Run function, both the main.py and moudlescript.py runs ok. But when I change to command line tool , it still gives the error. After checking project's properties. I found that there's a PYTHONPATH defined, which is workspace-relative

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but the error got fixed when I changed

```
from .BaseModel import BaseModel
```

to

```
from base.BaseModel import BaseModel
```

Comment: sorry for bad english

Comment: This was already mentioned by juanpa.arrivillaga in a comment below the question.

Comment: oh sorry didnt see